# Is there any event to catch improperly shutting down application?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I have wpf, c#, sql express application, which means software with database. Let's say I have a tab item, inside tab item there are data grids. From one data grid I buy staff and put it to Basket Data grid. Suppose in my main data grid there was 10 pencils and I bought 5. Now it is 5 in Main Data grid and 5 in Basket data grid. Until I press buy button it will stay in the Basket.
Now my question is, suppose electricity went down and my application is closed. In my main data grid is 5 and Basket is 0 after initializing. So I am losing what it was in my basket. I could manage it while closing application or closing tab items. But can not manage it, when application is closed improperly. Is there any mechanism, method, event to handle this in c#?
I know most of you will say use transaction, I will use in next version which will be not soon. For now I want to find how to deal with this with out transaction.
I hope you understand what I mean. Any ideas?

Here example
 Suppose you gave 12 pens and 15 pencils in your stock(Main data grid). And you are selling 2 pens and 5 pencils from you stock. And when you are selling it is going to Basket data grid. Now in Main data grid 10 pens and 10 pencils. In the basket 2 pens and 5 pencils. If I do not click submit button it will not be recorded in the sell data base. Suppose I am working and selling items from stock and electricity goes down. In my stock there are 10 pens and 10 pencils. Basket is empty. And it is not recorded in sell database because did not click button

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for, but you can use a battery backup and immediately flush everything to disk and shut down gracefully when the power fails.

Comment: So you update the DataGrid values (and remove items from the DB) but what is in the Basket is not saved in the DB? Is this what you are currently doing?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What does the data grib have to do with an application's process ending in a wierd way?

Comment: @CristianChereches Yes this the way I am doing. I am subtracting from Main data grid when adding to basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to set a dirty flag in the database along with the details of the basket when items are added.

Then when the checkout process completes clear the dirty flag.

Then when you restart the application check this flag. If it's clear then you can start from scratch. If it's set then pull back the details of the basket and deal with it however you need to.

It's not very clean but it will get the job done.

Comment: Very nice explanation, You showed me good direction. But the problem now is how to retrieve the details of the basket?

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov - you need to store them somewhere that will persist between sessions/invocations of your application. That could be local storage or even the database.

Comment: I will create temp table for basket and check it on application start, if there are items return back to Main data grid. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I am still not exactly sure how this works in your code, but I will give you answers for both ways:

1. If you store only the inventory data (data that goes in the Main Grid) in the DB, then when the app is closed, you will lose everything in the Basket because the memory is lost. If this is the case, your only solution is to also store the data in the Basket in the DB.
2. If you store bot the inventory and the basket data in the DB, then you have some code like this:

```
    update inventory
    update basket
```

If your problem is that the application is closed forcefully between those two lines of code, then the only solution is to add a transaction scope:

```
start transaction
update inventory
update basket
end transaction
```

This is the only way to insure data safety.

In case you are in case 1 you should implement the solution, but that will actually bring you in case 2. So I suggest that you do not wait until next version to implement transaction scopes.

I hope this helps.